# What is the "default" font for iPad mail program

Tags: ipad, mail.app, font

I was playing around with my new iPad. I was in email. Using yahoo
mail but it is a function of email as it is the same for spectrum mail
and google mail in the iPad email icon. I changed the font to see how
it looked without taking notice of the actual name of the font. There
are many to choose from and **I simply want to go back**. All I can see is
"default" for the one I have. I tried opening an old mail to see what
it was. (It was "default.")

What was it before I changed it? (To get the original font back.)

Answer (score 2):

It should be San Francisco, the system typeface in iOS, see [Apple Typography guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/)

I tried to check comparing it to similar typefaces both in iPad mail and in TextEdit.

Here's mail.
[image: iPad]
Here's TextEdit.
[image]

I took "i"s and "a"s as a confirmation that the default is SF.
You can see that the length of the first lines are different, but SF has [different tracking](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) depending on the context.

And yes, it doesn't seem to be possible to choose again the default font in iPad mail...
I succeeded in getting it back by pasting the text somewhere else (i used the Notes app) and copy-pasting again in mail.

Comment: San Francisco is not listed as a font! (forwarded from S.I.L. to me.)

Comment: You're right, this means you can't go back to the default font. That's why I propose to paste the text somewhere (where you don't have typeface selection, _e.g._ in Notes) and then copy-paste it back in a new email. I tried, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can check iOS Mail behavior by sending yourself an email and then in Mac Mail do View > Message > Raw Source to see what font name is specified in the underlying code.

When I did this I found that no font was specified. The email was plain text, so the recipient's default font would be used for display.

(This is also the default behavior for MacOS Mail)

Answer (score 0):

Hevetica Regular 12 is the standard in Apple Mail on macOS, it should be the same on iPad, try to compare this font with an old mail.